# Refresh subview of NIB/custom tableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview

I want to pop-up a subview NIB/custom tableViewCell to a view controller. The issue is when I click the map point, the pop-up keep overlapping with the latest click result. I want the subview refresh instead of keep popping a new one.

```
 //Pop up map details
    GLfloat topOffset = self.view.frame.size.height/3.6;
    UIView *modalView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LocateUsDetailsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [modalView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), topOffset)];
    [self.view addSubview:modalView]; //reloads the view from the nib
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{
        CGRect currentRect = modalView.frame;
        currentRect.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height/1.35;
        [modalView setAlpha:1];
        [modalView setFrame:currentRect];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:modalView];
    }];
```

Comment: change the Duration from 0 to some value 0.5 of 1

Comment: @Dhiru It's not about the duration issue

Comment: can you please explain more using Pic ?

Comment: If you want the subview to be refreshed then why are you call addSubview method? Maybe you want to remove previous modal (for example by keeping the reference to this modal somewhere in your class and call [self.modal removeFromSuperview];) and then addSubview for the new one. I'm just guessing ;)

Comment: @MichalCichon Hmm, first click on map location I want it to show the subview. Second click on different map location I want it refresh.

Comment: @NurII Why do you want to refresh it? If you have some UILabels or other elements in your modal view (why it is TableViewCell?) then you can always update its value but you need to have a reference to it. You could try to create a reference to UIView somewhere in your ViewController (for example in viewDidLoad method) and in your click event delegate just remove it and insert.